# using an Image as a key

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to use an Image as a key in a dict in Python?

```
answer_List = {One : 1, Two : 2, Three :3, Four : 4, Five : 5, Six : 6}
```

where 1-6 are png files. I am new to python and I keep reading that it is super flexible and anything can be stored in and as anything. Yet I am getting an error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'PngImageFile'

thanks.

Comment: this should help -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603365

Comment: In most usecase this will not be a good design. But it possible by sub-classing `PngImageFile` and making it [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#pyc-invalidation). The hash could be based on the file content, but the object must not change then.

Answer (score 1):

An object must be hashable if it is to be used as a dictionary key. I.e. it must have (or inherit) a [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you needed values associated with your images, you could for instance use their filenames as keys:

```py
{One.filename: 1, Two.filename: 2, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for a dictionary key is that you want it to be immutable. If you make a change to the key object the internal data structure of the dict will get messed up.

Images are very mutable, you can change a pixel at any time. Mutable objects don't bother to implement the `__hash__` method because it would be useless. That's what the error message is telling you.

It's better to use a *proxy* for the image. One good suggestion in another answer is to use the filename of the image, but that assumes that each image comes from a file and there aren't any duplicate images with different filenames. Another would be to freeze the contents of the image into something immutable like a bytestring, but that would be extremely inefficient because the bytestring would be large. You can cure that problem by using a cryptographic hash to produce a string that is unique for each image input.

```
import hashlib

def ImageID(im):
    return hashlib.md5(im.tobytes()).hexdigest()
```

This technique is useful for more than just `dict`s. I've used it for database keys for mp3 cover images, since many files will share an image.

Comment: You can even use a [perceptual hash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash) if you want cropped/rotated images to hash to the same thing. It works decently but far from perfect.